# ¿Cómo añadir cantidad a icono de carrito?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy intentando agregar la cantidad a un icono de carrito, el problema es que lo tengo alineado a la izquierda del carrito, y no logro acomodarlo de manera 100% responsive a la derecha de éste.

Mi código:

```css
#carrito-icon-menu {
  margin-top: 1.2%;
  margin-left: 0.5% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

#carrito-cont-menu {
  @include borde(black);
  //padding:5px;
}

#cantidad {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 85%;
  background-color: $naranja;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-menu-carrito right-addon" id="carrito-cont-menu">
  <span id="cantidad"> <strong><?php $usuario->mostrarCantidad();?></strong></span>
  <img src="elementos_separados/icon-carrito.png" class="" alt="" id="carrito-icon-menu" width="28">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para alinear o colocar contenidos a izquierda y derecha te recomiendo dos cosas: agrupar los elementos en una caja padre, y a la caja padre le das un tamaño.

Ejemplo:

```
<div style="width:100px;position:absolute;left:0;">
  <span style="float:left;"></span>
  <img style="float:right;max-width:20px;">
</div>
```

Básicamente lo que estás haciendo aquí es darle 100px de máximo a la ***caja contenedora o padre*** que contiene la imagen del carrito + más la cantidad. Después posicionas la caja donde quieras de tu navegador.

Si el carrito y su cantidad lo quieres fijo en una barra de navegación siempre visible, cambia el `absolute` por `fixed` y se quedará fijo a lo largo de toda la web.

En este punto tenemos dos opciones,

1. La primera opción, le aplicas un `float:right` o `float:left` a cada elemento SPAN + imagen, y dejas su ancho automático.
   Entonces te da igual el orden de tu HTML si es "Span + img" o "img + span" ya que el float lo llevará donde debe o quieres que se posicione, siempre dentro de su caja padre.
2. La segunda solución para el SPAN + IMG, es darles un ancho respecto de su padre, sin usar float, es decir:

Pero de esta forma, tendrás que cambiar el orden si va primero la imagen o la cantidad.

```
<div style="width:100px;">
   <img style="width:50%;">
   <span style="width:50%;"></span>
</div>
```

Por el flujo normal de carga del html y css, primero en la caja padre de 100px, entrará el primer elemento con el 50%(la mitad) del espacio de esa caja, y despues entrará otro elemento con un ancho de (la otra mitad) 50%, y por tanto, entran cada cual en su zona, pero dependerá del orden de tu HTML.

Está claro que puedes jugar con los % del ancho de cada caja en función del tamaño para la imagen y la cantidad haciendo que ambos sumen 100%.
Si por alguna razón al usar 50% y 50%, no se situan en horizontal uno al lado de otro, esto es por que o bien la imagen o el span tienen margin o padding, y este hace que el ancho sea mas del 100% y por tanto no se pueden colocar uno al lado del otro, en este caso, utiliza un porcentaje menor, como el 49% + 49% y te funcionará.